# Add a static element to a CollectionView

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to have a CollectionView render a `<ul>` container, with it's items as `<li>`'s, and insert a static `<li>` item in at the end? We are iterating over an array of objects that are rendered as links, and would like a "new" link to be inserted at the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyApp.TheView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  content: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  tagName: 'ul',
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{view.content}}")
  }),
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.pushObject(Ember.View.create({
      tagName: 'li',
      template: Em.Handlebars.compile("<button>NEW</button>")
    }));
  }
})
```

This should help...

Comment: this is not posible anymore. Any ideas on how to do it now?

Comment: @OscarVGG Can you post a fiddle so that I can update it, need to see why this isn't working now

Comment: Just one thing to add. `this.get('childViews').pushObject(...` should be replaced with `this.pushObject(...` as direct manipulation of "childViews" is deprecated